# ROW_NUMBER() with INNER JOIN SQL Server 2008 Pagination

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pagination

I am trying to connect two tables together with INNER JOIN and limit the amount of results displayed per page with ROW_NUMBER:

```
$tsql = "SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY productID) AS
rownum, * FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID
        WHERE category1 = '1') AS products1
WHERE rownum >= 0 AND rownum <= 6";

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);

 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){ 
        echo $row['productID']. "<br/>";
         echo $row['product_name']. "<br/>";

  }
```

I get "sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource" error , and I know it has something to do with me using INNER JOIN, because if I run the query without it I get results displayed on my page:

```
$tsql = "SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY productID) AS
rownum, * FROM products ) AS products1
WHERE rownum >= 0 AND rownum <= 6";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you talking about MS SQL server.
I don't code in php, but you should check first the following things:

1. Does your query works use SQL only (MS SQL in SSMS)
2. you specific column names, maybe you have double named columns! e.g. two columns named "id"
   Then you you 2times the same solumn in your result, no problem for SQL, 
   but a problem for most database connector drivers
3. If all don't work, make a query ( CREATE QUERY qry_yourQuery AS  ) 
   Use the SELECT * FROM qry_yourQuery then